# How to change reset password email subject in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3

I am beginner in Laravel. Currently I am learning this framework. My curent Laravel version is 5.3.

I am scaffolding my auth by using `php artisan make:auth` All are working fine. Also I configured gmail smtp in my .env file and mail.php in config directgory. All are perfectly working. But I saw by-default the forgot password email subject is going `Reset Password`. I want to change that.

I saw some blog. I found some blog. I have implement that in my site. But same output coming.

I followed these links -

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-password-reset-link-subject

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/reset-password-email-subject

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-override-message-in-sendresetlinkemail-in-forgotpasswordcontroller

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can change your password reset email subject, but it will need some extra work. First, you need to create your own implementation of [`ResetPassword`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php) notification.

Create a new notification class inside`app\Notifications` directory, let's named it `ResetPassword.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class ResetPassword extends Notification
{
    public $token;

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Your Reset Password Subject Here')
            ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
            ->action('Reset Password', url('password/reset', $this->token))
            ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
    }
}
```

You can also generate the notification template using artisan command:

```
php artisan make:notification ResetPassword
```

Or you can simply copy-paste the above code. As you may notice this notification class is pretty similar with the default [`Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php). You can actually just extend it from the default `ResetPassword` class.

The only difference is here, you add a new method call to define the email's subject:

```
return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Your Reset Password Subject Here')
```

You may read more about [Mail Notifications here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#mail-notifications).

Secondly, on your `app\User.php` file, you need to override the default `sendPasswordResetNotification()` method defined by [`Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/CanResetPassword.php) trait. Now you should use your own `ResetPassword` implementation:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\ResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    ...

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        // Your your own implementation.
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```

And now your reset password email subject should be updated!

[image: Reset password email subject updated]

Hope this help!

Comment: and how can we change regards Laravel and Laravel written at top.

Comment: @Steve Go to config/app.php and change the application name

Comment: @kniteli how to change that From : Example *****@****.com. I want to change that example.

Comment: @JayMomaya you can add this to your `.env` file   `MAIL_FROM_NAME="Example"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="*****@****"`

Comment: You can also use `$this->from('example@example.com');` in this example to change the sender at runtime.

Comment: I followed all the steps but errors 
"Class 'App\CustomResetpassword' not found".  Please help

Comment: What will be the url for this

Comment: How to change the laravel logo image displayed in the email??

Answer (score 5):

You may easily modify the notification class used to send the password reset link to the user. To get started, override the `sendPasswordResetNotification` method on your User model. Within this method, you may send the notification using any notification class you choose. The password reset `$token` is the first argument received by the method, See the [Doc for Customization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passwords#password-customization)

```
/**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

In `Laravel 5.7` the default implementation is similar to this:

```
return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::getFromJson('Reset Password Notification'))
            ->line(Lang::getFromJson('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
            ->action(Lang::getFromJson('Reset Password'), url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
            ->line(Lang::getFromJson('This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.users.expire')]))
            ->line(Lang::getFromJson('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
```

All you have to do is change your `locale` from `config/app.php` for example to `ro`, then in your `resources/lang`, create a file `ro.json` similar to this:

```
{
  "Reset Password Notification": "Viața Medicală CMS :: Resetare parolă",
  "Hello!": "Salut,",
  "You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.": "Primești acest email deoarece am primit o solicitare de resetare a parolei pentru contul tău.",
  "Reset Password": "Reseteză parola",
  "This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.": "Acest link va expira în :count de minute.",
  "If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.": "Dacă nu ai solicitat resetarea parolei, nu este necesară nicio altă acțiune.",
  "Regards": "Toate cele bune",
  "Oh no": "O, nu",
  "Whoops!": "Hopa!",
  "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\ninto your web browser: [:actionURL](:actionURL)": "Dacă nu reușești să dai click pe butonul de \":actionText\", dă copy-paste la URL-ul de mai jos în browser:\n [:actionURL](:actionURL)"
}
```

It will translate both the subject (first key) and the mail body.

**UPDATE for Laravel 6.***
This can be also used for `VerifyEmail.php` notification.

Answer (score 5):

**Laravel 8**

In AuthServiceProvider.php

Add these code.

```
ResetPassword::toMailUsing(function ($notifiable, $url) {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
            ->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
            ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), $url)
            ->line(Lang::get('This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.' . config('auth.defaults.passwords') . '.expire')]))
            ->line(Lang::get('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Second param is $token, not $url. This code doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

To everyone asking how to update the Hello, Regards, and subcopy text:

`php artisan vendor:publish` (option 11)

then in views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php

In this file there will be the text like Hello, wich you can change by changing:
for example:
line 9`# @lang('Hallo!, Hei!, Bonjour!, Guten Tag!,   Geia!')`

Comment: Depending on the libraries one is using the options is not necessarily the number 11, the option to select is *Tag: laravel-notifications*. In alternative the full command can be used `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications`

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom function that will create the reset password token like this.

```
 $user = User::where('email', 'example@name.com' )->first();
 $password_broker = app(PasswordBroker::class); //so we can have dependency injection
 $token = $password_broker->createToken($user); //create reset password token
 $password_broker->emailResetLink($user, $token, function (Message $message) {
         $message->subject('Custom Email title');
 });//send email.
```

Answer (score -1):

a note about this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40574428/9784378

you can copy vendor file functions and paste them into Resetpassword.php file
that you have created in notification folder .

Answer (score -1):

This is for Laravel 9 if you do not want to create new notification class.

Add this in the boot() method in the App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php

```
ResetPassword::toMailUsing(function (object $notifiable, string $token) {
    
    $url = url(route('password.reset', [
        'token' => $token,
        'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset(),
    ], false));

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
        ->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
        ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), $url)
        ->line(Lang::get('This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')]))
        ->line(Lang::get('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'))
});
```

Comment: Seems the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69475339/1255289) from 18 months ago.

Comment: that post's callback args is passing a $url but it's actually a $token string that you have to convert to a URL

Answer (score -6):

Just add the line:

->subject('New Subjetc')

in the the method toMail of the file Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword
like this:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('New Subjetc')
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
        ->action('Restaurar Contraseña', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

Comment: Bad idea. Never overwrite the Laravel code, but write your own!