# Override password reset url in email template Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, email, routes, passwords, reset

I am trying to override the actionUrl that is being put in an Email to reset a users account. But it stays the same no matter what I do. I tried overriding in my Route files. Can anybody help me ?

Here is the route in my routes file :

```
Route::get('cms/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
```

Here is my email template :

```
<p style="{{ $style['paragraph-sub'] }}">
    <a style="{{ $style['anchor'] }}" href="{{ $actionUrl }}" target="_blank">
        {{ $actionUrl }}
    </a>
</p>`
```

I know actionUrl is defined in SimpleMessage.php but I don't know where it's set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link is set in `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword`. This is the notification being sent out on a password reset request.

This notification is initialized in `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword` which is a trait pulled in nowhere else, than your `App\User` model.

So all you need to do is to create your own reset notification and override the `sendPasswordResetNotification` method on your `User` model, as shown below:

---

`php artisan make:notification MyResetPasswordNotification`

Edit `app/Notifications/MyResetPasswordNotification.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;


class MyResetPasswordNotification extends \Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword
{
    /**
     * Build the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
            ->action('Reset Password', url('YOUR URL', $this->token))
            ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
    }
}
```

Then add this to `app/User.php`

```php
/**
 * Send the password reset notification.
 *
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new \App\Notifications\MyResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

---

Of course, you'll need to create your own route, as you wrote in the question and you'll have to change blade views too.

Comment: After I figured this out, I found this other answer, which basically the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40574428/898783

Comment: Thank you very much, I wish you a nice day 