# How to change laravel 5.5 forgot password template and sender name?

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have two questions:

1. How to change laravel 5.5 forgot password template and sender name?
2. What's a proper eMail template design?

[image: how to change laravel 5.5 forgot password template and sender name?]

Comment: Alternatively you could consult the [Laravel Mail Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail) and read things there.

Answer (score 1):

You should be changing your *from address & name* in your `.env` file, or your `config/mail.php` file if you couldn't find it in your `.env`. You should be looking for `from` in your `config/mail.php`.

```
       'from' => [ 
                'address' => 'no-reply@example.com',
                'name' => 'Support'
        ],
```

As for changing the email template, you should look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40574428/3209381).

Answer (score 0):

Publish the vendor template first by running

`php artisan vendor:publish`

in your CLI. Select the appropriate vendor (`laravel-mail`). If everything works out fine you'll get a message stating

> Copied Directory
>   [/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/resources/views] To
>   [/resources/views/vendor/mail] Publishing complete.

Mailtemplates are available in `/resources/views/vendor/mail` for you to edit.

Comment: unable to find /resources/views/vendor/mail  laravel 5.5

Comment: unable to "Example" title change

Comment: Change the sender name in either `config/mail.php` or in your `.env` file (MAIL_FROM_NAME)